# VaR montecarlo simulation matlab

Tags: matlab, var, montecarlo

i'm working on matlab for the thesis and i need some help. i need to calculate Value at Risk using montecarlo simulation method.
the imputs is:
a equity portfolio with daily observation : nx5 array with n daily prices observation and 5 different stockprices.

i want to generate 10000 simluations with  normal distribution (and t-student) for returns and get the VaR. is important there is correlation between returns and the stock price has a gbm dynamic. someone can help me with code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, this site is more for when you have tried to approach a problem, but are stuck or having errors, rather than just asking someone to do the work for you, I'd suggest making a start yourself, explaining how you get on, and what issues you have, I think people will be more likely to help. Good luck! :)